# Delphi Soap Client example using OverByte ICS components?

Tags: delphi, soap, icalendar

I am looking for a sample SOAP client for Delphi using the [OverByte Internet Component Suite](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html), a non-blocking socket library.  The demos for OverByte ICS include basic HTTP client and server, but not SOAP.

I am hoping that someone has a demo, or can point the steps to making SOAP work using ICS.

Comment: Try to check [this demo](http://www.overbyte.be/arch/SoapGoogleDemo.zip) directly from OverByte. Hope this helps because I'm not familiar with this component suite at all :)

Comment: @daemon_x: You should post your comment as an answer.  This looks like it's exactly what Warren is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To plug in Soap in a HTTP client or server using the standard Soap library in Delphi, you can use the [ObjectToSOAP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/de/InvokeRegistry.TRemotable.ObjectToSOAP) and [SOAPToObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/de/InvokeRegistry.TRemotable.SOAPToObject) methods of TRemotable as a starting point. These methods serialize / deserialize objects derived from TRemotable to / from XML.